# Why is PHP so popular in contract work?

Tags: php, contract

I've decided I'm going to learn the skills to make websites with the hopes of maybe doing contract work one day.  Currently I'm dabbling with Django, but I get the impression that most contract work is done in PHP.  Why is that?

Comment: Easy to learn. Easy to host. Cheap to maintain & host. I do have to say that some of the worst projects that I've ever seen were PHP projects.

Comment: Belongs on http://programmers.stackexchange.com/

Comment: A bit subjective for StackOverflow… but answered anyway :P

Comment: It's not that PHP is popular for *contract work*, it's that *PHP is popular*. Why that is is anyone's guess, it's not a very answerable question.

Answer (score 3):

It's the VB 4-6 of web 2.0.  You really CAN do very nice scalable, organized things with PHP.  Most people don't, though, just like VB Classic.

Answer (score 2):

It's easy to find a PHP developer, since it's easy for almost anyone to produce functional PHP code. The most popular technology in the industry may not be the strongest in the long run, but it's best-known simply due to the number of people who can use it.

Comment: This answer, if true, is deeply alarming to me.